# Remove sub array item in knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

What would be the best way to remove an item from an observable array which is an item of another observable array itself? Let me provide an example (simplified).

Let's say I have an observable array 'chats':

```
self.chats = ko.observableArray();
```

this is my chat object:

```
function chat(id, name, members) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.members = ko.observableArray(members);
}
```

and here is the members object:

```
function member(id, username) {
    this.id = id;
    this.username = username;
}
```

I want to remove a member from chats array but I know only the id of a member and I don't know anything about a chat it belongs to. Is there any better way than looping through all `chat` items (using `ko.utils.arrayForEach`) and than all `member` items and check against the id?

Comment: can the member be in more than one chat?

Comment: No a particular member will be only in one chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a map to map the member ids to any chats that they are in.  IE:

```
var memberMap = {};
...
//on add
if(!(memberId in memberMap){
    memberMap[memberId] = [chatRef]
}
else{
    memberMap[memberId].push(chatRef);
}
```

Then you'll have cached references to the chat objects so you can search those member lists directly.

#### Update

Since there is apparently a 1-1 member to chat relationship the membermap code can just look like this

```
var memberMap = {};
...
//on add
    memberMap[memberId] = chatRef;
```

Answer (score 0):

Granted, I'm not too familiar with knockout.js, but is it possible for you to add a new property to the member class called 'chat'?

Essentially, every time a member becomes associated with a chat somehow, you update that property with the chat ID so that you could more easily link the two when the time comes to perform an operation that requires properties from both the chat and members object.

If you want, feel free to make chat into a private 'property' by declaring it as a variable inside the constructor; that way, you can only reference 'chat' through any getter/setter method that you write.

Comment: he says he only has an id for the member, not a reference to it, so this solution would also require a map of ids to references.

Comment: Good point. For some reason, I assumed he already maintained a separate map containing all the members.